# Merging two querys

Tags: linq, entity-framework

What is the best way to go about joining two querys in linq? At the moment my code does not join them together.

```
var userprofilemodel1 =
(from u in db.UserProfiles
where u.UserId == 1
orderby u.FirstName, u.LastName
select new UserListViewModel
{
   UserId = u.UserId,
   UserName = u.UserName,
   FirstName = u.FirstName,
   LastName = u.LastName,
   DocumentCount = u.Documents.Count
}).ToPagedList(page, 10);


var userprofilemodel2  =
(from u in db.UserProfiles
where u.UserId == 18
orderby u.FirstName, u.LastName
select new UserListViewModel
{
    UserId = u.UserId,
    UserName = u.UserName,
    FirstName = u.FirstName,
    LastName = u.LastName,
    DocumentCount = u.Documents.Count
}).ToPagedList(page, 10);


userprofilemodel1.Concat(userprofilemodel2);
```

Comment: You need to be clearer in what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this should do it:

```
var userprofilemodel1 =
(from u in db.UserProfiles
where u.UserId == 1 || u.UserId == 18 
orderby u.FirstName, u.LastName
select new UserListViewModel
{
   UserId = u.UserId,
   UserName = u.UserName,
   FirstName = u.FirstName,
   LastName = u.LastName,
   DocumentCount = u.Documents.Count
}).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

If you want/need to leave it as two separate queries but are trying to concatenate the results, then you need to realize that `Concat` *returns* a concatenated list - it does not *modify* either of the existing lists:

```
var mergedModel = userprofilemodel1.Concat(userprofilemodel2);
```

Comment: That's not the point, the example was just to get an understaning on how to merge two querys. I am aware of this but does not help me at all.

Comment: @TrentStewart You should at least thank D Stanley for the help. No one deserves to help you here. I can't believe without the appreciation of other people's help, how can people keep answering your question in the future?

Comment: Either I'm missing something obvious or your question is poorly written.  Based on your response to my answer I'm leaning towards the latter.  My answer gives you a "merged" list (at least as I understand "merging").  If you want a more generic answer (i.e. non hard-coded IDs) then amend your question with more detail about your inputs and desired output.